# python3 pip fails to install jupyter on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I want to install jupyter on Win 10. I have been using python on linux, but this is my first time on Win 10.

when I execute `python -m pip install jupyter` on administrator, I got errors like this:

> The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
>   that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.
>   This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
>   support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
>   script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
>   maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.

any idea?

Comment: What is your python distribution and `pip` version?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Python 3.80 and Pip 19.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to get around this error by installing Anaconda, uninstalling Python 3.8.0 and installing Python 3.7.5 instead.

The Jupyter installation then ran successfully when I executed `pip install jupyter` with Git Bash in my C:\ drive using pip 19.2.3 (the default with Python 3.7.5).

Answer (score 1):

For those who encounter this and need to use Python 3.8+, make sure to update you setuptools to version 42.0.0 (or later).

Answer (score 0):

Install a version earlier than python 3.8 and the installation will work. Use CMD.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I am using 64-bit windows 10 but downloaded the 32-bit python installer because it is the default that appears on the 'downloads' page on the python.org site.  Uninstalled python 3.8.1, downloaded the 64-bit installer instead, and then ran 'pip install jupyterlab' using the pip version 19.2.3 that got installed with the 64-bit python instead of upgrading to pip version 19.3.1.  So if you are running a 64-bit version of windows, make sure you download the 64-bit python installer!